# Как из формы брать данные для FindOne Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

вот контроллер, как из формы взять id который будет в FindOne() на подобии FindOne($model->id)

```
public function actionIndex(){
        $model = TransferForm::FindOne(17);

        /*$model->id = '2412312';
        $model->mon = '2134';
        */

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
            $model->save();
            if ($model->save()){
                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('alert', [
                    'body'=>Yii::t('frontend', 'Переведено'),
                    'options'=>['class'=>'alert-success']
                ]);
                return $this->refresh();
            }else {
                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('alert', [
                    'body'=>Yii::t('frontend', 'Ошибка.'),
                    'options'=>['class'=>'alert-success']
                ]);
            }
        }

        return $this->render('index', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял и Вам нужно получить с некой формы какой то `id`, то можно отсылать данные с формы методом `GET` на контроллер в `actionIndex` и там принимать свой `id` и искать данные. Например так:

`$model = TransferForm::FindOne(Yii::$app->request->get('id'));`